# Shortcut to switch panes in Split View on El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

El Capitan (?finally) provides a mechanism called Split View to Have two apps side-by-side in full screen mode.

I want to know if there exists, or how I'd go about implementing, a keyboard shortcut to switch/swap the panes while in Split View.

That is to say that the intended behaviour trigger is to take the left-pane and make it the right-pane and take the right-pane and make it the left-pane.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible. What a bummer. There is a topic on [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212588/keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-screens-on-split-view)

Answer (score 4):

There is no keyboard shortcut for doing what you have stated, but u can just drag the left-pane towards the right side with you mouse on the menu bar.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Like the way how "simple" it is but took me awhile to discover this!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another *partial* solution. If you split your screen between two windows of the same program, e.g. Safari, then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) will toggle between the two.

Caveats and Special Cases:

- If for some reason this does not work, you probably don't have this shortcut enabled. The answer at https://superuser.com/a/187072 explains how to do this.
- This was tested on High Sierra, but should work just the same on El Capitan, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When using split view for two terminal windows you can split between them with cmd + left/rigt arrow. I have not figured out a way to switch between windows when using split view with other applications though.

Also, if it is two different applications you can switch between them using cmd + tab

Comment: The question is not answered with this description. Ayush Tanna's answer hits the point (see below)